# Google Wallet postback URL update problems

Tags: android-pay

Just read on Google's Group for Wallet merchant support that the forum was being moved here, to stack overflow. Anyway, this is really a question for google's engineers. I have updated the postback URL multiple times from our google wallet merchant account, and every time have been greeted with the following message: "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later."

Later, when I refresh the page a few minutes following, the new postback url that I entered will appear to have taken. However, our merchant account will still not postback to the right URL. Sometimes this corrects itself 6-8 hours after entry --- other times it does not.

What gives? I'm very frustrated with google's in-app digital goods service for the preceding reason and am close to seeking out an alternate solution (even after 10+ developer hours implementing this with our subscriptions registration system)

Comment: No response from google and continuous errors even on their new stripped-down wallet/checkout-replacement lead our team over to Stripe for payments processing--- it's fantastic, has a lean but very versatile feature set for selling online services, digital goods, and subscriptions.